# Implement my own swipe on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement in my `UITableView` two options for edit:

1.When user swipe on `UITableViewCell` it will get `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`.

2.When user press Edit Button the `UITableView` will enter to edit mode (that I define by my self in the `UITableViewCell` .m file:

```
-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ( (selectionButton.superview == self.contentView && !editing) || (selectionButton.superview != self && editing))
    {
        // REMOVE BUTTON
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

        if (self.editingStyle != UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            if (!editing)
            {
                if (selectionButton.superview == self.contentView)
                {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
                    {
                        selectionButton.alpha = 0;
                        CGRect btnFrame = selectionButton.frame;
                        btnFrame.origin.x -= 120;
                        selectionButton.frame = btnFrame;
                    }
                                 completion:    ^(BOOL done)
                    {
                        [selectionButton removeFromSuperview];
                    }
                 ];
                }
            }
            else {
                // ADD BUTTON
                if (selectionButton.superview != self.contentView)
                {
                    [self.contentView addSubview:selectionButton];
                    selectionButton.alpha = 0;
                    selectionButton.center = CGPointMake(-self.contentView.frame.origin.x / 2 - 30, self.frame.size.height / 2);
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
                    {
                        selectionButton.alpha = 1;
                         selectionButton.center = CGPointMake(-self.contentView.frame.origin.x / 2 + 3, self.frame.size.height / 2);
                     }];
                }
            }

            [self setNeedsLayout];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add this delegate method to my `UITableView` :

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (table.editing) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    //  return 3;
}
```

but the problem is that function called 3 times when I swipe my finger on the cell.

There is any way to fix it? or it build-in in the `UITableView` that when the user swipe is finger on a cell this method called?

can I implement my own `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and make the delegate function call only when press the edit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a UIGestureRecognizer directly to the cell and notify the view controller of the swipe and perform your edit?